# Different Activity Items for individual Activity Activities in an UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to use different activity items for each activity activities in a `UIActivityViewController`? For example, I have the following code:

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[schemeURL, wordedString];
controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

// Exclude all activities except AirDrop.
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to set the data to send to Facebook to the `wordedString` property and set the data to send via AirDrop to the property `schemeURL`. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please confirm if this worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass UIActivityItemProvider and following method can be used to check activity type.. try it out

```
//- Returns the data object to be acted upon. (required)
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
    NSString *theText = @"Some text for Facebook";
    return theText;
}

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
    NSString *theText = @"Some text for Twitter";
    return theText;
}

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]) {
    NSString *theText = @"Some text for Weibo";
    return theText;
}

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
    NSString *theText = _someText;
    return theText;
}

if ([activityType isEqualToString:kYourCustomMailType]) {
    NSString *theText = @"Some text for your Custom Type";
    return theText;
    }

return @"Some default text";
```

}

Comment: Subclassing UIActivityItemProvider is primarily when you want the "providing of the shared item to be async". If all you want is to customize the payload per activity you should instead create an object that conforms to the UIActivityItemSource protocol.

Comment: @the1pawan  Hi there, can you please confirm if this worked for you ?